# Returning the middle node in a singly Linked List (Java)

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've forgotten basically everything from my DSA class because I'm an idiot, so I'm spending winter break refreshing myself and doing practice problems I find online. One of them is returning the middle node in a singly Linked List. If there are two middle nodes, return the second one. The posted solution is way different from my answer and I can't figure out why mine is wrong.

My implementation is basically:

```
public static Integer findMiddle() {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList();
    list.add(5);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(11);
    list.add(13);
    list.add(15);
    list.add(17);
    return list.get(list.size()/2);
}
```

EDIT: Here is the given online answer:

```
void printMiddle()
    {
    Node slow_ptr = head;
    Node fast_ptr = head;

    while (fast_ptr != null && fast_ptr.next != null) {
        fast_ptr = fast_ptr.next.next;
        slow_ptr = slow_ptr.next;
    }
    System.out.println("The middle element is ["
                       + slow_ptr.data + "] \n");
}
```

But the online answer is a bit more complicated than that. I don't really understand why this is wrong (again, I'm an idiot). If the linked list holds Integers, I would be returning the Integer, right? What would be the benefit of returning a Node over returning the object in the list, like you would in an ArrayList?

Thank you to anyone reading this! I know this is a silly question I just don't quite understand why.

Comment: If the task is to get the node why are you returning the object?

Comment: Actually **posting** the code you do not understand would be helpful. To your implementation: if the goal is to return the value in the middle of the list, I would have implemented it the same way you did.

Comment: How do you determine that your code is wrong? That the proposed solution from the book is different doesn't mean yours is wrong.

Comment: @Turing85 I edited the post with the given answer, I should have done that in the first place, my bad!

Comment: @K.Nicholas That's what I'm confused about, I'm not sure of the difference between returning the Node and returning the object, practically speaking. Is the answer just "Because the question tells you to" or is there something I'm not understanding conceptually (which is what I think it is)?

Comment: The provided answer operates under the assumption that we do not know the size of the list.

Comment: @Turing85 Yeah, the idea was to write a method that works on any given list. I get why it would throw that Exception though, that makes sense. I guess I just don't really understand Nodes? When I use the built-in LinkedList .add() method, is it adding the object directly into the list or into a Node in the list? What would be the difference between returning the object in the list vs. returning the Node?

Comment: My comment wrt. the `NPE` was wrong, I have edited it. --- The node is normally something internal to the datastructure, and not exposed. It is normally only used internally.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems very much like what you're attempting to solve: https://leetcode.com/problems/middle-of-the-linked-list/

But short of seeing the *exact question* you're provided, the "book answer" you have is very likely assuming you don't have access to the whole list; rather, just the head (entry point) `ListNode`. Which means you're going to have to traverse it to the end, and that's where the Slow & Fast Pointer technique is useful.

If we assume the question provides access to the entire LinkedList object, then your answer is fine, since you can get its `size()/2`.

Comment: Oh, that is similar! I got mine here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-function-to-print-the-middle-of-the-linked-list/

The G4G one says given a full list, so I guess another part of my confusion was why you have to traverse it at all. I understand now why you have to traverse it if you only have the head, thank you so much for explaining that!!